Use relationship with a SQLAlchemy Table object

I want to use relationship with sqlalchemy Table object.


Book = Table(
    "books",
    metadata,
    Column("id",Integer,primary_key=True,index=True),
    Column("title",String,nullable=False)
)


Page = Table(
    "pages",
    metadata,
    Column("id",Integer,primary_key=True,index=True),
    Column("nmae",String,nullable=False),
    Column("book_id",Integer,ForeignKey('books.id'),nullable=False,
                    index=True)
)


book.pages => How to apply


Use ORM, or just write a function/method to do what you want?
